# How can I implement transfer list with search in material ui?

Tags: material-ui

I googled the title.

But I couldn't find any tips.

I have a lot of data in transfer list.

Is there any solution to find data easier?

If you know anything plz tell me.

Answer (score -1):

I used `Transfer` from Ant Design for now.

```
import { Transfer } from 'antd';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    mockData: [],
    targetKeys: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getMock();
  }

  getMock = () => {
    const targetKeys = [];
    const mockData = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      const data = {
        key: i.toString(),
        title: `content${i + 1}`,
        description: `description of content${i + 1}`,
        chosen: Math.random() * 2 > 1,
      };
      if (data.chosen) {
        targetKeys.push(data.key);
      }
      mockData.push(data);
    }
    this.setState({ mockData, targetKeys });
  };

  filterOption = (inputValue, option) => option.description.indexOf(inputValue) > -1;

  handleChange = targetKeys => {
    this.setState({ targetKeys });
  };

  handleSearch = (dir, value) => {
    console.log('search:', dir, value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Transfer
        dataSource={this.state.mockData}
        showSearch
        filterOption={this.filterOption}
        targetKeys={this.state.targetKeys}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onSearch={this.handleSearch}
        render={item => item.title}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

https://ant.design/components/transfer/

Comment: The original post mentions to implement the transfer list with search in material-ui rather than ant design.

Comment: please provide material-ui not ant design